# dns records issue for www/nonwww version of my site

Tags: apache, web, dns, bind, cname

Im having some troubles with the site.com and www.site.com version.

At this time the "www" is working, but if I access to the site without it I get a DNS error.

I have a VPS machine with ubuntu and bind9

Everything is OK, except the dns zone created for that domain.

I cant find a combination of A, CNAME, ALIAS or any record that load the site with both versions.

This is what I have on the dns zone:

```
www             IN      A       10.0.0.0
```

This line make the www version works fine.

Now, I want the non-www version, and I tested the following codes without luck.

```
@               IN      A       10.0.0.0
@               IN      ALIAS   www
@               IN      ALIAS   www.site.com.
www             IN      A       10.0.0.0
@               IN      CNAME   www

@   IN  A   10.0.0.0
www IN  ALIAS   10.0.0.0


site.com. IN A 10.0.0.0
www IN CNAME site.com.
```

Nothing works. I really need both versions.
The apache site config file is OK the alias and server name are right, but it looks like a dns problem.

Any idea? It will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a sysadmin question, not programming.

Comment: There's no such thing as `ALIAS` in DNS. `CNAME` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@   IN  A       10.0.0.0
www IN  CNAME   @
```